# how to add another attribute using foreach loop to an array of rows

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I am using a `foreach` loop on an array of rows in a model file in `CodeIgniter`.
What i want to do is reflect the changes i make in every row ,in the `foreach` loop ,to the original array.

```
        $unique = $this->db->get_where('list', array('item_index' => $item));
        foreach ($unique->result_array() as $row)

            {
                $row["status"]= "Not Unique";
            if($row["bid_amount"]==$amount)
                {
                    if($count==0){ $row["status"]="Unique and Final"; }
                    else {$row["status"]="Unique but Not Final"; }

                }

                $count++;

            }   
        return $unique;
```

I am adding another attribute to each row here and i want to echo this attribute corresponding to each row in a view file.
But i am getting error  `Undefined index: status`.
How can i possibly reflect the changes in the array to be returned.

Comment: I do not want to copy all the attributes of `$unique` in a fresh 2-d array ,for each row, and add another attribute `status` to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign the `result_array()` to a variable, iterate over it, but change the original array and not the local one. PHP's `foreach` comes in two flavours:

`foreach($arr as $value)` and `foreach($arr as $key => $value)`

Try this:

```
$results = $unique->result_array();
foreach ($results as $rK => $rV){
    $results[$rK]["status"]= "Not Unique";
    //other stuff.
}
return $results;
```

Alternatively, you can pass by reference:

```
foreach ($results as &$result) {
    $result['status'] = "Not Unique";
}
```

See the [PHP docs on arrays.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.examples.changeloop) Specifically Example 10.

Answer (score 1):

In your foreach the `$row` refers to a variable that's local to the loop. Thus changing it does not affect the data in `$unique`.

Comment: I understand that now but i cannot find a way to reflect the changes to every row in  `$unique`.